# Clone Git repository in Linux using https protocol

Tags: git

I am trying to clone a repository in Linux using this command:

```
git clone username@https://host:port/repository.git
```

But I keep getting error.

Can someone please tell me the correct command to clone a repository on linux using https?

Comment: Did you bother looking at the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)? `https://user@host:port/...`

Comment: what error u got ?

Comment: General computing tip: When you're asking about an error, always copy the entire output verbatim and show it to whoever you're asking. Even if it doesn't mean anything to you, it's probably useful to someone who can answer your question. It's very hard to guess the solution to a problem you can't see.

Comment: I tried the suggestion given by @Marc B.. and I get the below error: -

(gnome-ssh-askpass:22135): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

I am trying to setup on Linux
(GIT Version installed is git version 1.7.1)

Comment: i also tried
git clone https://username:password@hostname/path/to/repository.git/

But I got the error: -
Initialized empty Git repository in /folder/.git/
error:  while accessing https://username:password@hostname/path/to/repository.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what errors or issues you're facing.

You can try to simply clone from the https and enter your username and password on prompt

```
git clone https://host/repository.git
```

Then again I **strongly** recommend switching to ssh if you're planning to use git often on the local machine

Comment: That's wrong. You can specify the username in a URL

Comment: Wups, thanks. Will be corrected, however I still recommend ssh over https

Comment: @CTXz SSH (often) isn't possible behind corporate firewalls.